# Excel VBA - Graph Update Loop

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, graph

Having trouble with the below code I've written. It should be updating the entries of a graph that previously ran from DL5:HX5 to DL5:IU5, have around 100 sheets hence the loop. For some reason it's stepping through but I appear to have a semantic error. Was hoping somebody might shed some light as to what that was.

There are three figures, and I'm not sure this is the best way to access figures on multiple sheets (they're identical copies of one another, with different data.) The first two just extends the time series the additional columns (e.g. HX to IU), the last figure simply color formats a line to a different color (the line is split by projected and actual line fragments.)

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 31 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

On Error Resume Next

Worksheets(i).ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "='" & Worksheets(i).Name & "'!$DL$5:$IU$5"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='" & Worksheets(i).Name & "'!$DL$3:$IU$3"

Worksheets(i).ChartObjects("Chart 6").Activate
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "='" & Worksheets(i).Name & "'!$DL$14:$IU$14"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = "='" & Worksheets(i).Name & "'!$DL$15:$IU$15"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Values = "='" & Worksheets(i).Name & "'!$DL$16:$IU$16"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).XValues = "='" & Worksheets(i).Name & "'!$DL$3:$IU$3"

Worksheets(i).ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(30).Border.Color = RGB(69, 114, 167)
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(30).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(69, 114, 167)

Next i
```

Comment: Comment out the `On Error Resume Next`.  Do you get an error? If Yes what is it, and on which line does it occur?

Comment: Thanks for the solution idea. I attempted it, runs into the same error (appears to run but ends up not changing the values.) I commented out On Error (I should have known to do that immediately!) and same problem, appears to run as normal but no changes are being made.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in the loop does it actually go through the code?

Comment: It appeared to run the loop fine with a breakpoint (I used Range("A3") = "Test" to see if it stepped between and it went fine.)

Comment: I think I may have found the error. Somehow on about 30 sheets, the ChartObject for one of the Graphs is Chart 13, not Chart 2 (how this became, I don't know. I'm unsure how to edit/assign Chart object designations as I'm fairly new to VBA.) What's weird is, when I was stepping through the original code it would select Chart 2 correctly (using the Activate function) but in reality if you use Record Macro - Developer that Chart shows as "Chart 13" when activated.

Comment: I have no ideas - (my) code looks good to me, and if it's not then you should get an error.  Possibly it's not updating what you expect it to update?

Comment: If you select the chart you can rename it under *Chart tools >> Layout >> Chart name*

Comment: This is indeed the solution! Thanks so much for the help Tim. Is there a method I could use to rename all those who have a "Chart 13" to "Chart 2" using Boolean logic and a loop? (I would upvote but as you can see, I am a fish on stackoverflow :))

Comment: Instead of using the default "Chart 2" type of chart name, use more descriptive names, like "ChtRevenue", "ChtMargin", etc. Select each chart, and enter the name you want to use in the name box (in the formula bar above cell A1).

Comment: copy-paste of my comment below: Beware of Excel insane behavior: if you `.ChartObjects("Chart 1").name = "Chart 2"` then `?.ChartObjects("Chart 1").name` prints "Chart 2"... also `?.ChartObjects("Chart 2").name` prints "Chart 2"... so now `ChartObjects("Chart 1")` and `ChartObjects("Chart 2")` refer to the same object... WTF Microsoft !?

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid activating/selecting where you can.  Untested:

```
Sub Tester()

Dim i As Integer
Dim sht As Worksheet

    For i = 31 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i)

        With sht.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Chart.SeriesCollection(1)
            .Values = sht.Range("$DL$5:$IU$5")
            .XValues = sht.Range("$DL$3:$IU$3")
        End With

        With sht.ChartObjects("Chart 6").Chart
            .SeriesCollection(1).Values = sht.Range("$DL$14:$IU$14")
            .SeriesCollection(2).Values = sht.Range("$DL$15:$IU$15")
            .SeriesCollection(3).Values = sht.Range("$DL$16:$IU$16")
            .SeriesCollection(3).XValues = sht.Range("$DL$3:$IU$3")
        End With

        With sht.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(30)
            .Border.Color = RGB(69, 114, 167)
            .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(69, 114, 167)
        End With

    Next i

End Sub
```

EDIT: renaming charts

```
For i = 31 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i)
            on error resume next
            .chartobjects("Chart 13").Name = "Chart 2"
            on error goto 0
        End With
Next i
```

Comment: Beware of Excel insane behavior: if you `.ChartObjects("Chart 1").name = "Chart 2"` then `?.ChartObjects("Chart 1").name` prints "Chart 2"... also `?.ChartObjects("Chart 2").name` prints "Chart 2"... so now `ChartObjects("Chart 1")` and `ChartObjects("Chart 2")` refer to the same object... WTF Microsoft !?